# How to set word wrap left alignment in list using css

Tags: html, css, blogs

On my blog page [qavalidation.com](http://qavalidation.com/2018/02/sublime-text-3-x-download-setup-customize-run-python.html/), I have vertical menus with links, when I do word wrap, it's not aligning with proper left indention, please guide me with proper css to make it proper alignment

Here is the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/r7k9sueu/1/

Currently it's

`--- Download and setup python on
windows machine`

but I want

`--- Download and setup python on
     windows machine`

Actual Image

[image]

Comment: How about a minimal code example showing us your problem?

Comment: I dn't have much idea on how to try basic css changes, still I tried with ```.dtree a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}``` 
but no luck...

Comment: Please set up a minimal code example e.g. here: https://jsfiddle.net/. You likely won't get any help without providing some code showing what you've already tried.

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/r7k9sueu/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a before element like below and delete the imgs:

```
.dtNode {
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 20px;
}

.dtNode:before {
 position: absolute;
 content:"";
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 background-image: url(http://qavalidation.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-dtree-30/dtree-img/page.gif);
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dtNode"><a id="smnu25" class="node" href="http://qavalidation.com/2018/01/know-write-selenium-test-using-python.html/" title="Know how to write Selenium test using Python" onclick="javascript: mnu2.s(5);">Know how to write Selenium test using Python</a> </div>
```

remove the images which is already there. and use it as background to the anchor tag with the `padding-left 25px`

```
.dtNode a{ padding-left:25px; 
 backgorund:url(filename ) 0 0 no-repeat;)
}
```

this is not the exact code for your styling because you have not provided me the code i am just suggesting an answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>another item</li>
    <li>a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long item</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
li:before {
  content: "-";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're after `list-style-position`, e.g.

```
ul {
  list-style-position: outside;
  padding-left: 12px;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should change the div tags into an li tags, then remove the empty gifs that, and then add a padding to each li tag, to have something like this :

```
<ul>
  <li style ="padding-let: 20px;"><li>
  <li style ="padding-let: 20px;"><li>
  <li style ="padding-let: 20px;"><li>
</ul>
```

here is a js fiddle with your code :

https://jsfiddle.net/omtjm9zL/2/